# Why is there plain form in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The following examplatory sentence in the grammar section of my textbook:
どうして医者になりたいんですか。
...医者は人を**助けるすばらしい**仕事だからです。

It translates to (according to my textbook):
Why do you want to become a medical doctor?
...Because medical doctor is a great job in which you help people.

What confuses me is that in the bold part, there is no connective form like て form or ます stem. I know plain form as a way to make a verbal expression an attribute to the related noun. In my textbook, it is said that a plain-form-sentence + からだ expresses the reason(s) for an event. However, is it necessary to omit other grammatical habits like the aforementioned て and ます form for chaining verbal expressions inside the respective clause?
I just want to avoid being confused down the road when I'm encountering such constructions in the wild :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > どうして医者になりたいんですか。
> > ...医者は人を**助けるすばらしい**仕事だからです。
>
> It translates to (according to my textbook): Why do you want to become a medical doctor? ...Because medical doctor is a great job in which you help people.
>
> in the bold part, there is no connective form like て form or ます stem.
> I know ***plain form as a way to make a verbal expression an attribute to the related noun***.

I think you are talking about 連体形{れんたいけい} here, and this grammar point is the answer to your case. The modifying adjective (すばらしい) might have caused your confusion. The noun that is modified by a relative clause can also take other adjectives.

> 医者は〔人を**助ける**〕〔（すばらしい）**仕事**〕だからです。

/

> In my textbook, it is said that a plain-form-sentence + からだ expresses the reason(s) for an event. However, is it necessary to omit other grammatical habits like the aforementioned て and ます form for chaining verbal expressions inside the respective clause?

Yes, we say 助けるからだ to express a reason, and yes, to connect a verb with the
particle て, or a helping verb like ます, た, etc., the verb form is conjugated to the particular form (連用形{れんようけい}): 助けてくれた, 助けます, 助けた, etc. So, this form is not to connect to a noun. It's like the English conjunction 'and': 彼は小さいころから親{おや}を**助けて働{はたら}いた.**

Answer (score 4):

It should be parsed as:

> 医者は［人を助ける］［すばらしい］仕事だからです。

人を助ける and すばらしい both modify the noun 仕事.
人を助ける is a relative clause here.

［人を助ける］仕事 = a job [in which you help people]
［すばらしい］仕事 = a [wonderful] job

You could also see it as ［人を助ける（すばらしい仕事）］, the relative clause 人を助ける modifying the noun phrase すばらしい仕事.

Hence the translation:

"Because medical doctor is a [wonderful] job [in which you help people]."

A few examples with the same structure:

> - ［友達に会える］［楽しい］場所 -- a [pleasant] place [where I can see friends]
> - ［私の部屋にある］［かわいい］時計 -- a [cute] clock [in my room]
> - ［あの子が履いている］［赤い］くつ -- [red] shoes [that the girl is wearing]

---

> I know plain form as a way to make a verbal expression an attribute to the related noun.

Correct. The plain form 助ける is the attributive form here and modifies the noun 仕事.

> In my textbook, it is said that a plain-form-sentence + からだ expresses the reason(s) for an event.

Precisely. 「医者は（人を助ける）（すばらしい）仕事だ。」 is a plain-form-sentence. ～～からだ/～～からです added at the end means "Because~~" "It's because~~", indicating that the whole sentence is a reason for some event or action.

Answer (score 2):

Because 助ける is used as a noun modifier of 仕事. When using a verb as noun modifier, it's always in plain form.

If you were to use the て form it becomes:
医者は人を助けて、すばらしい仕事だからです。 
Which I think roughly translates into: "Doctors help people, because it's a great job."

Comment: `医者は人を助けて、すばらしい仕事だからです` doesn't sound very natural... and it doesn't mean "Doctors help people, because it's a great job", either.